# Spring MVC View bringing field with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, view, jstl

I have a class named `Categoria` child of `OneField` in my Model.

I create the following code on the Controller:

```
CategoriaDAO categoriadao = new CategoriaDAO();
List<Categoria> categorialist = categoriadao.getCategorias();
model.addAttribute("categoriaList",categorialist);
```

Its working perfecly, bringing the results as espected. So I wrote the following code in the View:

```
<c:forEach items="categoriaList" var="categoriaElement">
<option value="${categoriaElement.nome}">${categoriaElement.nome}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

And I'm getting the following error:

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'nome' not found on type java.lang.String`

The field `Nome` is in the `OneField` class and not in the `Categoria` class. How can I get the Nome in the view through the `Categoria` class?

Comment: Does it work when you use a property from the Categoria class? The error says the property is not found on 'java.lang.String'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 
`<c:forEach items="categoriaList" var="categoriaElement">` 
to 
`<c:forEach items="${categoriaList}" var="categoriaElement">`

You are currently passing to the c:forEach tag library the string "categoriaList" instead of the model attribute with this name